# Hive (0.12.0) - Load data into table with partition, buckets and attached index

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Using Hive 0.12.0, I am looking to populate a table that is partitioned and uses buckets with data stored on HDFS. I would also like to create an index of this table on a foreign key which I will use a lot when joining tables.

I have a working solution but something tells me it is very inefficient.

Here is what I do:
I load my data in a "flat" intermediate table (no partition, no buckets):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'myFile' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE my_flat_table;
```

Then I select the data I need from this flat table and insert it into the final partitioned and bucketed table:

```
FROM my_flat_table
  INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE final_table
  PARTITION(date)
  SELECT
  col1, col2, col3, to_date(my_date) AS date;
```

The bucketing was defined earlier when I created my final table:

```
 CREATE TABLE final_table
   (col1 TYPE1, col2 TYPE2, col3 TYPE3)
   PARTITIONED BY (date DATE)
   CLUSTERED BY (col2) INTO 64 BUCKETS;
```

And finally, I create the index on the same column I use for bucketing (is that even useful?):

```
CREATE INDEX final_table_index ON TABLE final_table (col2) AS 'COMPACT';
```

All of this is obviously really slow, so how would I go about optimizing the loading process?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I had a similar requirement, I used almost the same approach being used by you as I couldn't find an efficiently working alternative.

However to make the process of `Dynamic Partitioning` a bit fast, I tried setting few configuration parameters like:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict; 
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true; 
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions = 2000;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode = 10000;
```

I am sure you must be using the first two, and the last two you can set depending on your data size.

You can check out this [Configuration Properties](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties) page and decide for yourself which parameters might help in making your process fast e.g. increasing number of reducers used.

I can not guarantee that using this approach will save your time but definitely you will make the most out of your cluster set up.

Comment: I am indeed using the first two, I will try the last ones, thank you!
Good to know that someone else has done the same thing I have.